# iOS Swift 4 Firebase Send message to multiples users

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I build chat app using Firebase as database. My chat 1 to 1 works fine but i want to create list of users and send message to all users of selected list... How i can do that?

This is my sendMessage func

```
fileprivate func sendMessageWithProperties(_ properties: [String: AnyObject]) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("messages")
    let childRef = ref.childByAutoId()
    let toId = user!.id!
    let fromId = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let timestamp = Int(Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
    
    var values: [String: AnyObject] = ["toId": toId as AnyObject, "fromId": fromId as AnyObject, "timestamp": timestamp as AnyObject]
    
    properties.forEach({values[$0] = $1})
    
    childRef.updateChildValues(values) { (error, ref) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        
        self.inputContainerView.inputTextField.text = nil
        
        let userMessagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(fromId).child(toId)
        
        let messageId = childRef.key
        userMessagesRef.updateChildValues([messageId: 1])
        
        let recipientUserMessagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(toId).child(fromId)
        recipientUserMessagesRef.updateChildValues([messageId: 1])
    }
}
```

Messages table:
[image: a busy cat]

User-Messages table:
[image: a busy cat]

Users table:
[image: a busy cat]

Comment: It would help if we could see your database structure. From you code I can see that everything is saved into `messages` node. Imagine how many entries will you have inside `messages` when a lot of people use your app. I don't think this is the right approach. I would suggest creating groups. Each conversation between users, forms a new node inside `messages` - lets say user A and B create a conversation, it generates new node in: `messages/key1`. Now every message they compose is saved inside `messages/key1` instead of `messages`. You would then apply save logic for group chats.

Comment: How are you sending messages to a list of users; i.e. are you sending messages to users regardless of if they want the message or not or have the users subscribed to a list and requested messages. i.e. getting spammed or did they elect to get messages. That design decision will drive how your database is structured and how messages are sent.